# Node.js - Passing variables dilemma

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have my main (main as in package.json) set to app.js, it starts a web server.

I need to return the server variable to other files. I added:
`module.exports = server;`

But it returns an empty table. As far as I know, module.exports is only ran on required, so app.js won't be run on any require, as it will have been ran by the node command.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you're running `node .` or `npm start` or whatnot, which launches `app.js`, where are you expecting anything to get returned _to_?

Comment: app.js creates the server, I was requiring it before module.exports was actually called, so I fixed it by moving module.exports right below creating the server